# Finding a download URL from the NuGet OData feed

Tags: nuget

What's the trick for deriving a download URL given an entry in the Packages table in the OData data set?

Comment: Ah, what was I thinking - anyways, you can just edit the question directly

Answer (score 0):

< content type="application/zip" src="***SOME-URL***" />

Answer (score 0):

Under the `<entry/>` node, look for a `<content/>` node which contains 2 attributes `type` and `src`. The `src` attribute contains the download url. You could use LINQ to XML to get it. Seems easy, right? Oh, and remember to append an `XNamespace` to the `XName` when using LINQ to XML to query the nodes.